# Preselecting a value of dropdown based on data from API

Tags: reactjs

This is my code when creating a new entry. Then when I fetch the item details I want to preselect a dropdown like text input boxes are prefilled during editing based on the API response. I have commented on where I want to preselect

`

```
import Select from "react-select";
                             
    function Vehicles() {
       const [statusSelected, setStatusSelected] = useState(null);
       const [openAddCarDialog, setOpenAddCarDialog] = useState(false);
       const [carName, setCarName] = useState("");
    
       const handleStatusChange = (e) => {
           setStatusSelected(e);
       };
                    
       const statusDropdown = [
          {
            value: "Available",
            label: "Available",
          },
          {
            value: "Booked",
            label: "Booked",
          },
       ];
       //Here i am submitting new data
       const handleSubmit = (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          const carData = {
             car_name: data.car_name,
             status: statusSelected.value,
          }
          axios.post("https://api/v1/newcar", carData)
               .then((response) => {
                  handleClose();
                  getAllVehicles();
               });
          };   
       //Here i am fetching new data to prefill input
       const getDetails = (carId, e) => { fetch(`https://api/v1/cars/${carId}`)
             .then((response) => response.json())
             .then((data) => {
                setCarName(data.single_car.car_name);
                //here i am attempting to preselect data but it's not working
                if (data.single_car.status === "Available"){
                   setStatusSelected("Available");
                } else if (data.single_car.status === "Booked"){
                      setStatusSelected("Booked");
                  }
                },
                (error) => {
                  setLoading(false);
                  setError(error);
                }
              );
          };  
              
         return(
           <div>
              <Dialog open={openAddCarDialog} onClose{handleClose}>
                 <div>
                   {editable ? (
                   //editing new item
                   <form>
                      <div>
                         <div>
                            <label>
                               Car name
                            </label>
                            <input
                               type="text"
                               name="car_name"
                               value={carName}
                               onChange={handleChange}
                               placeholder="Car name"/>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            //here is where i want to preselect
                             <Select
                                placeholder="Available/Booked"
                                value={statusSelected}
                                options={statusDropdown}
                                onChange={handleStatusChange}/>
                          </div>
                          <button
                             type="submit">
                               Edit Vehicle
                          </button>
                       </div>
                     </form>
                     ):(
                     //creating new item
                     <form>
                        <div>
                           <div> 
                              <input
                                 type="text"
                                 name="car_name"
                                 value={data.car_name}
                                 onChange={handleChange}
                                 placeholder="Car name"/>
                           </div>
                           <div>
                              <Select
                                 placeholder="Available/Booked"
                                 value={statusSelected}
                                 options={statusDropdown}
                                 onChange={handleStatusChange}/>
                           </div>
                           <button
                             onClick={handleSubmit}
                             type="submit">
                               New Vehicle
                          </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    )}
                </div>
           </Dialog>
        </div>
         )                   
    }
```

`
How can this be achieved I'm using react-select. Been stuck here for weeks

Comment: Please add your code as a code block

Comment: I have added as codeblock @AmilaSenadheera